# Ransack search has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have a Profile model:

```
has_one :job_preference, inverse_of: :profile, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_preference, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Job Preference model:

```
belongs_to :profile
has_many :job_preferences_wanted_locations
has_many :wanted_locations, through: :job_preferences_wanted_locations, dependent: :destroy
```

Job Preference Wanted location model:

```
class JobPreferencesWantedLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job_preference
  belongs_to :wanted_location

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :wanted_location
end
```

Wanted locations model:

```
class WantedLocation < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :job_preferences_wanted_locations
    has_many :job_preferences, through: :job_preferences_wanted_locations, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Im trying to use Ransack gem in the Profile index to make a query on wanted locations.**

I can access these wanted locations like this:

```
profile.job_preference.wanted_locations.each do |n|
    print n.name  
end
```

I have read through the Ransack doc and tried variations of:

```
job_preference_wanted_location_name_cont
```

but this doesnot seem to work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Im trying to use Ransack gem in the Profile index to make a query on wanted locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
job_preferences_job_preferences_wanted_locations_wanted_location_name_cont
```

from profile, to associative (job preference - wanted location), to wanted location itself and the name attribute.

The thing is that if I don't remember bad, ransack doesn't works directly with through associations.